# Can I setup a single-node etcdraft orderer cluster in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm manually setting up a fabric network. I want to know if I can setup an etcdraft orderer cluster with only one node at first and add more nodes in the future?

Actually, I've already bring the single orderer node up, but it failed to process requests with this error "Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- no Raft leader" which I think may be caused by not having the correct number of orderer nodes. That's why ask if a single-node etcdraft orderer cluster works.

Comment: After I posted this question, I went further to set up a 3-node raft orderer cluster. But I still got the error "Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- no Raft leader". So I knew that it was not the problem of how many nodes. 
What I forgot to mention in the original question is I worked on a Windows OS with Docker Desktop. After I inspected logs of the orderer servers I found that all three nodes became follower and there was no any leader election. 
I then switched to do the same deployment in a Linux environment where the cluster finally worked as expected.

Comment: So this is likely an OS specific problem(and most likely about file system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, a single-node etcdraft orderer will works according to documentation.

You can find tutorials with one raft orderer in documentation.

Link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#the-components-of-the-test-network

You may have to write configtx.yaml file according to following link.

Link:https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml

Adding a new node to a Raft cluster is done by:

Adding the TLS certificates of the new node to the channel through a channel configuration update transaction. Note: the new node must be added to the system channel before being added to one or more application channels.
Fetching the latest config block of the system channel from an orderer node that’s part of the system channel.
Ensuring that the node that will be added is part of the system channel by checking that the config block that was fetched includes the certificate of (soon to be) added node.
Starting the new Raft node with the path to the config block in the General.GenesisFile configuration parameter.
Waiting for the Raft node to replicate the blocks from existing nodes for all channels its certificates have been added to. After this step has been completed, the node begins servicing the channel.
Adding the endpoint of the newly added Raft node to the channel configuration of all channels.

Links: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/raft_configuration.html#reconfiguration

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the useful links.